# 5-bit signed binary to int

Tags: python, binary, int, signed

My code has to read 5-bit signed binary values. Let's say it reads a `11111`, which would be two's complement `-1`. But `int("0b11111", 2)` returns `31` instead.

How can I parse the correct value?

Comment: In what system is `11111(bin) == -1(dec)`?

Comment: Two's compliment, where the first bit represents the sign.

Comment: With 5 bits? I'd expect a multiple of 8, or at least of 2.

Comment: Should I extend it to 8 bits?

Comment: You have a 5-bit computer at home.?

Comment: I'm writing an emulator, and most of the values are set using 5 bits in the instructions.

Comment: `bin(-1)` is `-0b1`. You'll have to code the two's compliment manually.

Comment: I don't get the reason for the negative votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution testing all 5-length binary numbers of your future emulator:

```
import itertools


def two_complement(value, length):
    if (value & (1 << (length - 1))) != 0:
        value = value - (1 << length)
    return value

opcodes_emulator = ["".join(seq) for seq in itertools.product("01", repeat=5)]

for my_string in opcodes_emulator:
    print my_string, two_complement(int(my_string, 2), len(my_string))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!